# What is the purpose of limits header files in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

Why we use the header file called limits in c++.

```
#include<limits>
```

What are the uses and who we can use these.
Actually i have an assignment to explore the purpose of `limits` header file and also write a sample programme to use this. and i also i'm new to c++ programming language. I have intermediate knowledge about so i'm not new in programming but new in `c++`. I haven't read/study about loops, classes and functions in c++. I just need to know about `limits header file`?

Comment: Have a read through this nice reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits

Comment: Because we want access to the definitions within the file?  I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: Actually i have an assignment to explore the purpose of limits header file and also write a sample programme to use this. and i also i'm new to c++ programming language. I have intermediate knowledge about so i'm not new in programming but new in c++. I haven't read/study about loops, classes and functions in c++. I just need to know about limits header file?

Comment: @TimRandall help me.

Comment: The example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/ is probably what you need to do.

Comment: can you recommend me some video from YouTube. because i'm not able to understand whats going on here. @drescherjm

Comment: No. I don't watch many `c++` videos at all. I started programming in `c++` in early to mid 1990s. My `c++` skills come from a combination of several thousand+ page books and experience with writing code and reading other peoples code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why do we have this header?

In (most) other languages, the *precise* details of numeric types are defined by the language. In C++ there are some things left up to the implementation to define. `<limits>` provides a mechanism to inspect what the implementation has picked.

For example, the standard only specifies that `int` be a numeric type able to represent *at least* the range `[-32767, 32767]`. My machine has an `int` that can represent `[-2147483647, 2147483648]`, and there are others that are even wider.

A programmer may want their code to *fail to compile* on an implementation with particular choices.

```
int some_complex_algebra(int a, int b)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<int>::max() >= 2147483648, "This code assumes at least 32bit 2's complement int");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### What is this header for?

If you take a look at [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/), it tells you about its purpose:

> This header defines elements with the characteristics of arithmetic
>   types. More specifically, it defines a numeric_limits class template
>   and a specialization of it for each of the fundamental types:

It then goes on and mentions two enums that concern `float` rounding and denormal `floats`, as well as an elaborate page on `std::numeric_limits`. This defines various operations, such as

- Checking the minimum and maximum value that it can hold
- Checking whether it is a signed type, so whether minus numbers are possible
- Checking whether it supports values such as `infinity` or `NaN`
- Checking its rounding behavior

> i have an assignment to explore the purpose of limits header file and
>   also write a sample programme to use this.

You can find a nice example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/). Run the example and think of how they can be useful. For instance, perhaps you might be writing a program that does math on  big numbers, so maybe it could use those functions to check if the limits are too low and warn the user. Or it could check if a floating point number adheres to the IEEE-754 standard, which might be important if you want to send the number to a different device.